# "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing" while iterating a dictionary in PDB

Tags: python, twisted, pdb

I have a `pdb` trace set inside a `GET` request.  I want to print all the attributes of the request object. I am trying the following, in pdb:

```
(Pdb) request
<GET /foo HTTP/1.1>
(Pdb) for d in dir(request):
*** SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (<stdin>, line 1)
```

I am sure there is something fundamental I am missing here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't enter multi-line statements in `pdb`. You can use the `commands` command *if* the code block is to be executed on a break point, though; `help commands` for more information.

You can also sometimes collapse a multi-line statement into a single line. For example:

```
for d in dir(request): print d
```

In your particular case, though, it seems that either `print dir(request)` or `pp dir(request)` would suffice.

Comment: Thanks.  As I suspected, something fundamental.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this pointer!  I just assumed pdb worked the same way the ordinary `python` repl worked.

Answer (score 7):

At the pdb prompt, do the following:

```
(Pdb) a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
(Pdb) for i in a:
*** SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (<stdin>, line 1)
(Pdb) import code
(Pdb) code.interact(local=locals())
>>> for i in a:
...     print i
... 
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but there is an updated python debugger called `ipdb`.

It allows for having tab completion, color support and magic functions as well as all the original functionality of `pdb`.

And it allows for multiline `for loops`.