# Python "For Loop" is working in debug mode, but not when running it normally from terminal?

Tags: python, elementtree

Very amateur question incoming. I have this code to parse an XML with Elementtree. Then I run a for loop to show all child tags and attributes. If I run it in debug, I can see every nested element and data displayed in the terminal. However when I run the whole code with "shift+enter" (Using VSCode here).

It's giving me this error

(Pdb) for child in root.iter():
*** SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
(Pdb)     print (child.tag, child.attrib)
*** NameError: name 'child' is not defined
(Pdb)

Here is the code. Tried googling but i'm probably using the wrong keywords. Not finding anything clear about this.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('90301007.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
receiptid = "74925"
root.tag
root.attrib
for child in root.iter():
    print (child.tag, child.attrib)
```

Comment: Did this not help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777807/syntaxerror-unexpected-eof-while-parsing-while-iterating-a-dictionary-in-pdb

Comment: Yeah not sure how that didn't come up in the search results. However i'm legitimately not understanding the solution provided no matter how many times I read it. I have to right it as a single line? Seems convoluted if i have to write a whole function out of the loop and what it does with the data. I'm obviously missing some fundamental component. This is my first foray into python as a OOP programmer

Comment: I've never used `pdb` so I have no idea why that's happening. Seems like your IDE is not using the debugger correctly or something, I'm not sure. I only have ever used PyCharm, which works flawlessly with a debugger, so I've never run into that issue. Since there's a free community edition of that, I'd recommend that as it's more tailored to Python than VSCode.

Comment: The debugger actually works, it's when i run via PDB that it doesn't. Someone told me I should use iPython or something like that for interactive python scripts rather than PDB. I'll have to read up on interpreters and how/why they handle the execution differently

Comment: pdb is the Python debugger that is shipped with Python. If you simply want to run your code then it isn't the appropriate option (either use the REPL directly, the Interactive Window that comes w/ the Python extension for VS Code, or you can try IPython). As for why pdb is failing, I don't know and you can file a bug at https://bugs.python.org for it.

Comment: I mean i figured out I can just run the code via the powershell terminal with the Python command. It's the VSCode tutorial that got me using PDB but i guess its just not meant for what i'm doing/doesn't like multi line statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDB Isn't good for multi line statements. I'm running the code via powershell with the Python command and now it works fine. Was just weird that going line by line with debug would allow the code to work in PDB, but not running normally. Either way, the why's and how's I don't know, but python command does the trick here.